# Call multiple strings inside variable

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

Python scrub here.
Im still learning python so sorry.
Im trying to create a Dict(i think) that then behaves as a variable called fileshare and then want to call each entry inside the variable called fileshareARN. So basically inside the AWS ARN I want each share to be called. for example I want share-A, share-B, etc to be called each time. Im guessing I need to setup a function or a IF statement but im not sure.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('storagegateway')
fileshare = [share-A, share-B, share-C, share-D]

response = client.refresh_cache(
    FileShareARN='arn:aws:storagegateway:us-west-1:AWS-ID:share/{Fileshare-variable, share-ID should go here}.format',
    FolderList=['/'],
    Recursive=True
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close! A few notes to preface the answer to assist you on your Python journey:

- *Python does not allow hyphenated variable names*, as hyphens are a reserved operator for subtraction. You only had them listed as placeholders, but figured it would be helpful to know.
- `lists`, `arrays`, and `dictionaries` are all different data structures in Python. You can read about them more here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html , but for your particular use case, if you're simply trying to store a collection of variables and iterate over them, a list or array work fine (although a dictionary is usable as well).

---

In Python, `lists` and `arrays` are iterables, which means that they have built-in functions that can naturally be iterated over to sequentially access their constituent values.

Let's go over an example using the following array:
`fruits = ['apples','bananas','oranges']`,

In other languages, you're probably used to having to define your own loop with the following syntax:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOf(fruits); i++)
{
   print(fruits[i]);
}
```

Python enables this same functionality much more easily.

```
for item in fruits:
   print(item)
```

Here, the scope of the term `item` within the loop is equal to the value that exists at that current index in the array (`fruits`).

Now, to perform this same functionality for your example, we can use this same technique to loop over your list of ARNs:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('storagegateway')
fileshare = [shareA, shareB, shareC, shareD]

for path in fileshare:
    response = client.refresh_cache(
        FileShareARN='arn:aws:storagegateway:us-west-1:AWS-ID:share/'+path,
        FolderList=['/'],
        Recursive=True
    )
```

After changing the placeholder variables you had in fileshare, I wrapped the existing response variable execution with a `for` loop, and made a slight change to the string appending at the end of your `FileShareARN` variable.

Hope this helps, and welcome to Python!

Comment: Thank you for your input! Sorry for delayed response just got back from vacay.

Answer (score 0):

Did some more research, found f.string formatting which seems to make python life easy. Also since I am deploying this in AWS Lambda I added a handler.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
def default_handler( event, context ):
    print(boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity())

    client = boto3.client('storagegateway')
    fileshare = ['share-A', 'share-B', 'share-C', 'share-D']

for path in fileshare:
    response = client.refresh_cache(
        FileShareARN = f"arn:aws:storagegateway:us-west-1:ARN-ID:share/{path}",
        FolderList=['/'],
        Recursive=True
    )
    print(response)

default_handler( None, None )
```